# "Mono Debugger" not shown in MonoDevelop "Attach to Process" dialog

Tags: mono, debugging, monodevelop

I'm running MonoDevelop 2.2 Beta 1 with Mono 2.4.2.3 on Ubuntu 9.04 x64. I've compiled it all from source (had to, since it's a beta version). I have both GDB and MDB debuggers installed. When I open a C# project I can start it in the debugger and stop at a breakpoint, so it looks like the MDB debugger is working. However, if I select Run, Attach to Process the only value in the Debugger dropdown is "GNU Debugger (GDB)" - there is no "Mono Debugger" there! How do I fix this? I want to be able to attach to a .NET process, including ASP.NET.

In fact, if I disable the "GDB Debugger" addin then the "Attach to Process" menu item disappears entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Mono Debugger (MDB) doesn't currently support attaching to a process. This feature was enabled in the past, but it was disabled because it caused many stability issues. There are plans to support attaching again in future MDB/MonoDevelop releases.